# python gtk.window.resize not working when trying to make bigger/smaller window

Tags: python, linux, gtk, resize

I have a window that I start in a certain size and want to make smaller or bigger when user does an interaction.. I have made it into a top dock so nothing can maximize over it.

I cannot resize it to a smaller or bigger size, nothing happens.

Here is the code for me creating the window:

```
window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

box = gtk.VBox(homogeneous=False, spacing=0)
window.add(box)
box.pack_start(browser, expand=True, fill=True, padding=0)
window.set_default_size(gtk.gdk.screen_width(),500)
window.move(0, 0)
window.set_type_hint(gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DOCK)
window.show_all()
window.window.property_change("_NET_WM_STRUT", "CARDINAL", 32,
        gtk.gdk.PROP_MODE_REPLACE, [0, 0, 100, 0])
```

And here is the code i fire when user interacts:

```
window.resize(gtk.gdk.screen_width(),100)
```

It does not fire any error codes, but nothing happens..

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would work, just need to change this line:

```
window.resize(gtk.gdk.screen_width(),100) # Instead of gtk.gdk.screen.width()
```

and It would be better to use below line of code i.e.

```
window.window.property_change("_NET_WM_STRUT", "CARDINAL", 32,
    gtk.gdk.PROP_MODE_REPLACE, [0, 0, 100, 0])
```

after the

> window.show_all() command

otherwise it will raise error for "NoneType" object.

Your code with some modification:

```
import gtk

class ResizeWindow:

 def __init__(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    button = gtk.Button("Resize")
    self.window.add(button)
    button.connect("clicked", self.resizewin)
    self.window.set_default_size(gtk.gdk.screen_width(),500)
    self.window.move(0, 0)
    self.window.show_all()
    self.window.window.property_change("_NET_WM_STRUT", "CARDINAL", 32,
           gtk.gdk.PROP_MODE_REPLACE, [0, 0, 100, 0])

 def resizewin(self, widget, *args):
    self.window.resize(gtk.gdk.screen_width(),100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ResizeWindow()
  gtk.main()
```

Hope, it's the same which you want to do.

Comment: yea, thanks for pointing out my errors, I adjusted my original code, actually the gtk.gdk.screen.width was just a typo from me, I didn't cutnpaste directly so mistyped there. My post shows how my code is, but it is still not functioning.

Comment: hmm i just tried your code, which is essential the same as mine .. and that works.... Will dig a bit in my application to see what im doing wrong.. thanks for proving it works :p

Comment: I found out that my webkit window was causing the issue (which is not displayed here) I had to change it to a gtk.ScrolledWindow to make it all work.

Comment: Its not working when i have resolution of 1280x720 and resize it to 1280x330.